# Pass Variables between Static Forms using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am quite new to Ruby, but have some experience with programming. I am trying to figure out how to pass a variable collected in a form (SEARCH) using POST, to its controller (API) and then output it into another view (RESULT) that is also in the same controller.

I know the variable makes it to the API controller, because it shows up in the server log. But I can't figure out why it won't pass from there as an instance variable to the Result.html.erb page.

**Routes.rb**

```
Remixr::Application.routes.draw do
  get "api/search"
  post "api/result"
end
```

**search.html.erb**

```
<form action = "result" method="post">
    Zip Code: <input type = "text" size = "5" name = "zip_code" />
Search Range: <input type = "text" size = "3" name = "range" />    
              <input type = "submit" value="Search" />
              <input type = "reset" value="Reset Form" />
</form>
```

**result.html.erb**

```
Zipcode = <%= @zip_code %>
 Radius = <%= @range %>
```

**api_controller.rb**

```
def search
  end

  def result
    @zip_code = zip_code
    @range = range
  end   
end
```

I know this some rudimentary stuff here, but I can't find anyone that shows a form used in one view , POST the form contents to its own controller to use another method in that controller and then output variable made in that method to another view under the same controller. I cut out a lot of the other processing that is going on until I am sure that I can pass variables in the fashion I laid out.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, use:

```
def result
  @zip_code = params[:zip_code] 
  @range = params[:range]
end
```